# What is the MAXIMUM file upload size in PHP ini file

Tags: php, localhost

I have changed the upload_max_filesize to 150MB  in the php.ini file.

but  http://localhost/info.php shows the upload_max_filesize is still showing 16MB .

I have also restarted  the server.

what is the the problem?

I am unable to find the solution.

Comment: how did you find it shows 16MB?

Comment: @Sarfraz, you can use `ini_get("upload_max_filesize");`

Comment: PHP can have multiple .ini files, plus settings overrides in other places (like httpd.conf/.htaccess) - only the LAST override/setting will take effect, so try and figure out where your upload size setting is getting trashed.

Comment: @david: that doesn't work if you're doing it from within the upload handling script - the PHP code is not executed until **AFTER** the upload has completed. it's impossible to change upload-specific settings from within the script that the upload is going to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also upload_max_filesize should be changed in both php.ini files..
In the Apache folder, and the PHP folder..

Comment: How did you know there was a php.ini in the apache AND php folders? Seems like you're assuming the OP is using a specific environment.

Comment: sorry, my bad.. I assumed the server ran on linux.. Most webservers i have owned and used did, but maybe i was a bit too quick

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is larger than your `upload_max_filesize` value.

This limits the overall size of the POST body, which also has a bearing on the max upload size.

You will also need to ensure that [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is larger than `post_max_size`.

Comment: i had changed memory_limit =200 mb and post_max_size=180mb andupload_max_filesize =150 mb  still no change

Answer (score 0):

Locate the php.ini file inside the wp-admin directory (if you can’t find this file see notes below)

Find this line in the php.ini file “upload_max_filesize = 2M” and replace it with a higher value (e.g. “upload_max_filesize = 64M”)

You may also want to increase your max post size. Look for this line in your php.ini file “post_max_size” and increase it as well.
Save the changes to the file inside your wp-admin directory.
Try the upload again
If you still have issues, look for this file in your root directory and make the same changes.

Answer (score 0):

move your php folder insise your localhost directory, open php.ini
press control + f find upload_max_filesize change it from 2M to whatever you want, and also change post_max_size from 8M to again whatever u want,save changes , overwrite this php.ini file with file in php folder,restart your localhost and check it.